# Searching for themes that post full article on home page by default

Tags: themes, the-content, excerpt

I understand there is way to change `the_excerpt` to `the_content`. But do any of the existing "features" on the search feature (under add new themes) indicates the `the_content` is already the default option for the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The search function essentially captures [the header of the theme's `style.css` file](https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header), which contains two types of information that relate to the theme's properties.

There is a description, which holds a free text and there are some tags which must be chosen from a fixed list. The excerpt/content choice is not among the tags. The free text may contain some information, but it is not systematic data.